# PHP - Convert multidimensional associative array's key strings into numbers

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I have a multidimensional associative array like this:

```
$type = Array(
  [unit-1] = Array(
    [taxon-1] = Array(
      [0] = Array(
        [a] = 1,
        [b] = 1,
        [c] = 'string1'
      ),
      [1] = Array(
        [a] = 1,
        [b] = 1,
        [c] = 'string2'
      ),
    ),
    [taxon-2] = Array(
      [0] = Array(
        [a] = 1,
        [b] = 2,
        [c] = 'string3'
      ),
      [1] = Array(
        [a] = 1,
        [b] = 2,
        [c] = 'string4'
      ),
    ),
  [unit-2] = Array(
    [taxon-1] = Array(
      [0] = Array(
        [a] = 2,
        [b] = 1,
        [c] = 'string5'
      ),
      [1] = Array(
        [a] = 2,
        [b] = 1,
        [c] = 'string6'
      ),
    ),
    [taxon-2] = Array(
      [0] = Array(
        [a] = 2,
        [b] = 2,
        [c] = 'string7'
      ),
      [1] = Array(
        [a] = 2,
        [b] = 2,
        [c] = 'string8'
      ),
    ),
  )
```

How do I convert all the associative keys (unit-1, unit-2... and taxon-1, taxon-2...) into ordinals (0, 1... and 0, 1...). Do I need to use a foreach loop, and if yes, how would it go?

Please note that there is not a finite number of units and taxons in the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there's definitely two levels:

```
$type = array_values(array_map('array_values', $type));
```

To re-index all array keys from an array:

```
function array_reindex($array) {
    if(is_array($array)) {
        return array_map('array_reindex', array_values($array));
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Splendid. This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Yes, for now I only need two levels. Just wondering though, how much more complicated would it be if there were more levels?

Comment: Updated my answer with a function to recursively re-index an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for that.

Comment: Indeed I can, and it would work perfectly, but only for the first level of keys, i.e. unit-1, unit-2... Taxon keys would not be changed. How can I utilize array_values to apply recursively deeper into the array?